# What is difference betweent nextjs client component and normal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

This might be most basic question , but i would like to know the difference between client component(.client.js) and normal component(.js) in terms of basic difference and in  terms of rendering, like suppose does client components get server side rendered like normal components

Comment: Never heard of this but there are verities of code that need browser to run such as saving data into browser memory or getting the window height ie. browsers inner width. So such component only renders on client side. May be this is what you are asking.

Comment: Not exactly, even in client components (.client.js) if we just console.log(window), it still gives error window not defined.

Comment: Can you share documentation link where they have said to name file as .client.js

Comment: Docs [Next.Js server components](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/server-components#server-components-conventions) , well if it's just a convention in nextjs than really ntg much left to answer :-)